# how to get a last column value in a Templorary datatable (.net)

Tags: c#

I am storing some values in a temporary datatable.Sample values as follows

```
ID FILENAME         PATH
--------------------------
1   txt1            C:\NewFolder
2   txt2            C:\NewFolder
3   txt3            C:\NewFolder
```

I want to get the last value of ID column.

Comment: Is it the SQL table and you need the query? Or is it .NET `DataTable` which is already populated with the data?

Comment: i created a temp datatable in asp.net,not in sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use such code to get the last row and then the value from column ID:

```
object lastId = table.Rows[table.Rows.Count-1]["ID"];
```

If by last you meant that you need the maximum value from the table you can use the following LINQ query to get the result:

```
int maxValue= table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"])).Max();
```

You need to have the following `using` in order for it to work:

```
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      string expression = "1=1"

      // Sort descending by column named CompanyName. 
      string sortOrder = "ID DESC";
      DataRow[] foundRows;

      // Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
      foundRows = table.Select(expression, sortOrder);
      var row = foundRows[0];
```

Ref:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w(v=vs.110).aspx